# Angular 2 route is getting loaded into the top level router-outlet despite having a specified router-outlet defined on the route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Here you can see the problem:

[image: img]

`admin-area-models-models` should be rendered into the router-outlet with the name `models-content`, but instead it's put inside the same router-outlet as the parent module, which is `admin-area-models`. Which doesn't make any sense since I got this in the `admin-area-models` router:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ModelsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'brands',
    loadChildren: '../pages/+models-brands/models-brands.module#ModelsBrandsModule',
    outlet: 'models-content'
  },
  {
    path: 'models',
    loadChildren: '../pages/+models-models/models-models.module#ModelsModelsModule',
    outlet: 'models-content'
  },
  {
    path: 'models/:id',
    loadChildren: '../pages/+model/model.module#ModelModule',
    outlet: 'models-content'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ComponentsModule,
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    ModelsComponent
  ]
})

export class ModelsRouterModule {}
```

How come that when I have a specific outlet defined, it still renders it into the top level one?

**EDIT:**

If I change so that the routes are children are defined like this instead:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ModelsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'brands',
        loadChildren: '../pages/+models-brands/models-brands.module#ModelsBrandsModule',
        outlet: 'models-content'
      },
      {
        path: 'models',
        loadChildren: '../pages/+models-models/models-models.module#ModelsModelsModule',
        outlet: 'models-content'
      },
      {
        path: 'models/:id',
        loadChildren: '../pages/+model/model.module#ModelModule',
        outlet: 'models-content'
      }
    ]

  }
];
```

Then none of the routes work. `ModelsComponent` is at `/admin/dashboard/models`, so with the first config I showed all routes all accessible like this:

```
/admin/dashboard/models
/admin/dashboard/models/(models-content:brands)
/admin/dashboard/models/(models-content:models)
/admin/dashboard/models/(models-content:models/5) // Any number
```

But when trying out the config that uses `children`, I can no longer access any of these routes. Suggesting that using this syntax with lazy loaded files is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `admin-area-models-models` aren't children of your `admin-area-models`, your routes need to be something like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ModelsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'brands',
        loadChildren: '../pages/+models-brands/models-brands.module#ModelsBrandsModule',
        outlet: 'models-content'
      },
      {
        path: 'models',
        loadChildren: '../pages/+models-models/models-models.module#ModelsModelsModule',
        outlet: 'models-content'
      },
      {
        path: 'models/:id',
        loadChildren: '../pages/+model/model.module#ModelModule',
        outlet: 'models-content'
      }
    ]

  }
];
```

You want to render your auxiliary routes inside `admin-area-models` where you have your `<router-outlet name="models-content">`, but this how you are declaring your routes:

[image: Actual declaration]

And this how you want to render them:

[image: Correct way]

You clearly need to change your logic, because your routes are not siblings they are children of `admin-area-models`

Comment: That no longer gives me access to the `''` route, or any routes below that for that matter.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: that's because now your routes are something like this: `/admin/dashboard/models/brands`, `/admin/dashboard/models/models`, `/admin/dashboard/models/models/5`

Comment: But they're auxiliary routes, so they're not :|

Comment: Then you need to rethink your logic, because you are declaring them as siblings of your `models`, but then you want them to be a child of `models`, that's why they get rendered alongside your parent component

Comment: The logic is correct, but it's the rendering that's not correct. Whether it's the syntax or something else that I've forgotten to add.

Comment: I updated my answer, you do need to change your logic, because you are trying to render routes inside your component.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say, but my point is that I've already built it in a way, both in my folder structure and in the app itself, where `AdminAreaModels` is the parent of brands, models and models/:id. It's just the routing itself that I don't understand how to config correctly in order for the structure I got to be represented in the browser as well.